# Deleted Windows partition, now computer goes directly to BIOS

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

I've been dual-booting windows 10 and xubuntu 16.04 for about a year now. Recently, I had problems with Windows and was unable to use the recovery option so I decided to simply format the partition where it was installed. From that moment, every time I start my computer it goes straight to BIOS, as if Linux was no longer installed.

I tried using boot-repair from a live-usb. Here is the log:

http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/26202232/

If you need more information about my problem, don't hesitate asking. Right now I simply don't know what I should try or what information is relevant to my problem... Thank you.

Comment: looks like you deleted the EFI System partition. This partition is required to boot.

Comment: Running sudo fdisk -l, there is a EFI System partition at /dev/sda2. I don't think I modified it in any way.

Comment: sda2 is formatted ntfs .... FAT32 is required for ESP.

Comment: It worked! All I had to do was format sda2 to FAT32 and run boot-repair again. Thank you for your help :)